# How to do pagination in Google Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this list: `a b c d e f g h i j`. I want to get 3 items from the list around a selected item. If I have selected `e` the result list should be `d e f`, if I have selected `f` the results should be `e f g` and so on.

I made this example:

```
console.clear()
var pag = dbFirestore.collection("pagination")
pag.doc("a").set({parent:"vowels"})
pag.doc("e").set({parent:"vowels"})
pag.doc("i").set({parent:"vowels"})
pag.doc("o").set({parent:"vowels"})
pag.doc("u").set({parent:"vowels"})
pag.doc("y").set({parent:"vowels"})
pag.doc("b").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("c").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("d").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("f").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("g").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("h").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("j").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("k").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("l").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("m").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("n").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("p").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("q").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("r").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("s").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("t").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("v").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("w").set({parent:"consonants"})
pag.doc("x").set({parent:"consonants"})
var siblings = ref => {
    var out = []
    return pag.orderBy("parent").endAt(ref).limit(3).get().then(snap=>{
        snap.forEach(doc=>out.push(doc.id))
        return
    }).then(()=>{
        return pag.orderBy("parent").startAfter(ref).limit(2).get().then(snap=>{
        snap.forEach(doc=>out.push(doc.id))
        return out
        })
    })
}
siblings(pag.doc("m")).then(out=>{
    console.log(out)
}).catch(e=>console.error(e))
```

With `sibling("m").then(out=>console.log(out))` in `out` I should have `k l m n p`, they all have `parent:"consonants"`, `k l m` from the first query combined with `n p` from the second query, but I have something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are forming your query.  `startAt`, `endAt`, etc operate on the fields you pass to `orderBy`.  So if you do `.orderBy("parent").startAt("foo")` that's saying "order all documents by the value of doc.parent, starting where doc.parent == foo".

So you'll have to make a few changes here.  First it will be easier to query if you store the value of the letter in the document, so your documents could look like this:

```
{
  "val": "a",
  "parent": "vowels"
}
```

And then you could do this query:

```
/**
 * ex: siblingsOf("a", "vowels");
 */
function siblingsOf(letter, parent) {
   var out = [];

   // Starting at the letter, read "up" three documents
   var threeBefore = pag.where("parent", "==", parent)
      .orderBy("val", "desc").startAt(letter).limit(3);

   // Starting after the letter, read "down" three documents
   var twoAfter = pag.where("parent", "==", parent)
      .orderBy("val").startAfter(letter).limit(2);

   return threeBefore.get().then(snap => {
     // Add to beginning of array
     snap.forEach(doc => out.unshift(doc.data()));
   }).then(() => {
     return twoAfter.get().then(snap => {
       // Add to end of array
       snap.forEach(doc => out.push(doc.data()));

       return out;
     });
   });
}
```

So if I did `siblingsOf("j", "consonants")` I would get the documents for `"g", "h", "j", "k", "l"`.

Comment: I added `{val:letter}` to all docs. `startAfter(letter)` works as expected gets `n p`, but: `pag.where("parent", "==", "consonants").orderBy("val").endAt("m").limit(3)` gets `b c d` the first 3 consonants instead of the prev `k l` plus `m`

Comment: @AlinC yes you are right I made a mistake.  In genera using `endAt` and `limit` together is not a good idea because the query results will end at whichever one of those is the stronger constraint.  Let me update.

Comment: I think we have left with using `unshift` instead of `push` for `threeBefore` because we get `m l k n p` instead of `k l m n p`. I'll try to update myself your answer. I can't edit it, I have to edit more then like 6 characters. Anyways I know how to paginate know, thanks.

Comment: Alin C, I Have the same problem with you The Firestore pagination doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There has documentation at firebase on [Pagination & Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). We have to use the startAt() or startAfter() methods to define the start point for a query. Similarly, use the endAt() or endBefore() methods to define an end point for your query results.